# How to extract small video chunk with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

I'm writing a script to **split a video in multiple small files based on subtitles timing**. Each chunk illustrated how to sign a word LSF (French Sign Language).

However, some file are blank once extracted and when converted to `webm` they are `0kb`.

#### Timing data

I extract the timing from a `.ass` file to get this kind of file

```
0:00:01.01 0:00:04.07
0:00:04.09 0:00:07.00
0:00:07.00 0:00:10.36
0:00:10.36 0:00:13.28
```

First column is `start_time`, second is `end_time`

#### Extraction

```
extract_word_chunk() {
  ffmpeg \
    -i "$INPUT_FILE" \
    -ss "$start" \
    -to "$end" \
    -vcodec copy \
    -acodec copy \
    -loglevel error \
    "$chunk" < /dev/null
}
```

#### Conversion to webm

```
convert_to_webm() {
  ffmpeg \
    -y \
    -i "$chunk" \
    -acodec libvorbis \
    -codec:v libvpx \
    -b:v 192k \
    -b:a 96k \
    -minrate 128k \
    -maxrate 256k \
    -bufsize 192k \
    -quality good \
    -cpu-used 2 \
    -deadline best \
    -loglevel error \
  "$chunk.webm" < /dev/null
}
```

#### Output

```
# extract_word_chunk
ffmpeg \
  -i 'assets/raw/partie 1: Apprendre 300 mots du quotidien en LSF.jauvert laura.mkv' \
  -ss 0:00:01.01 \
  -to 0:00:04.07 \
  -vcodec copy \
  -acodec copy \
  -loglevel error \
  assets/raw/0:00:01.01.mkv

# convert_to_webm
ffmpeg -y \
  -i assets/raw/0:00:01.01.mkv \
  -acodec libvorbis \
  -codec:v libvpx \
  -b:v 192k \
  -b:a 96k \
  -minrate 128k \
  -maxrate 256k \
  -bufsize 192k \
  -quality good \
  -cpu-used 2 \
  -deadline best \
  -loglevel error \
  assets/raw/0:00:01.01.mkv.webm
```

#### Error

```
[buffer @ 0x16d8be0] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
    Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0x16d8be0] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x16e6fc0] Error applying options to the filter.
```

#### Question

Only some chunk are blank/empty.

How do I prevent my video to be blank/empty?

Comment: related https://video.stackexchange.com/q/25365/23799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in one command

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -i 'assets/raw/partie 1: Apprendre 300 mots du quotidien en LSF.jauvert laura.mkv' \
  -ss 0:00:01.01 \
  -to 0:00:04.07 \
  -acodec libvorbis \
  -codec:v libvpx \
  -b:v 192k \
  -b:a 96k \
  -minrate 128k \
  -maxrate 256k \
  -bufsize 192k \
  -quality good \
  -cpu-used 2 \
  -deadline best \
  -loglevel error \
  assets/raw/0:00:01.01.mkv.webm
```

---

When you use `copy` mode, and decode seek (-ss after -i) ffmpeg only cuts at keyframes, so sometimes there may not be any keyframes in the time range specified, hence those output mkvs are empty. You can avoid this by extracting and encoding in one step.

Comment: Yes, I did. ... and  ?

Comment: Initally I thought it may have been incompatibility due to factors such as build, codecs, and implicit pixel format settings.  After re-interpreting the question, I think you are spot on - it's blank at the extraction stage and the error is just stating the obvious.  So yeah +1 this was helpful

Comment: @Gyan is there alternative solution? As per design I want to do this in 2 separate steps