# Splitting video in short clip result in some being empty?

Tags: bash, performance, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to split a video (50-100Mo) into several small clips of a few seconds each. I don't need re-encoding, hence my use of `codec copy`.

However some of the resulting clips don't have any video.

#### Fast but no video in some files

```
ffmpeg \
  -y \
  -i ./data/partie-1:-Apprendre-300-mots-du-quotidien-en-LSF.jauvert-laura.hd.mkv \
  -ss 0:00:07.00 \
  -codec copy \
  -loglevel error \
  -to 0:00:10.36 \
  'raw/0:00:07.00.au revoir.mkv'
```

I also tried `-map 0 -c copy`, `-acodec copy -map 0:a -vcodec copy -map 0:v` or no option related to codec.

#### Slow but complete

No argument related to audio/video encoding, it's working but pretty slow.

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -i "$SOURCE_VIDEO_FILE" \
  -ss 0:05:37.69 \
  -to 0:05:40.64 \
  -loglevel error
  'raw/0:05:37.69.pas la peine.mkv'
```

#### Question

How do I split a video into small chunk `~2-4s` when I have no need for re-encoding?

related: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/25365/23799

Comment: Isn't this related to your last Q at https://stackoverflow.com/q/47616933/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint can't be satisfied. Some video codecs appear to use chunks, where they start with a complete frame and then store "diffs", so in order to use `-vcodec copy`, ffmpeg has to honour the chunk boundaries.

Don't use `-vcodec copy` if you encounter this problem.